# What are some well-known, online news sources that are worthy of language study?

Tags: resources, reading, listening

I'm fluent in Chinese already. I just want to further my reading and writing skills.

I'm thinking along the lines of

- NPR - has both (audio) news and talk radio that can be accessed online
- Time Magazine, The Economist - current events and issues, etc
- New York Times - daily newspaper

But all in Chinese (either for China, Taiwan or any other Chinese population)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your demand, here are my picks. They're locally famous.

### China mainland

1. [南方人物周刊](http://www.nfpeople.com), a featured weekly on influencing people, with some exclusive interviews.
2. [南方周末](http://www.infzm.com), a weekly on politics, economics, culture, and especially recent (past week) controversial topics.
3. [新京报](http://www.bjnews.com.cn), a daily with Beijing (or China) features. Founded in 2003.
4. [财经网](http://www.caijing.com.cn), a good source for financial and business news.
5. [腾讯网](http://www.qq.com), a major Internet portal.
6. [三联生活周刊](http://www.lifeweek.com.cn), a major life style magazine.
7. [FT中文网](http://www.ftchinese.com), Chinese version of [Financial Times](http://www.ft.com), also with many Chinese columnists.
8. [China Daily 中文版](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/hqzx/), famous for its English version, a major English daily.
9. [财新网](http://www.caixin.com/), another good source for financial and business news.
10. [优酷网](http://www.youku.com), the biggest video portal, YouTube's copycat, even from its name.
11. [重庆晨报](http://epaper.cqcb.com/), for those who wanna have PDF version of newspaper, this one's for you.
12. [第一财经周刊](http://www.cbnweek.com/), a reader-friendly financial weekly.
13. [外滩画报](http://www.bundpic.com/), full of featured stories with pictures.

### Hong Kong

1. [亞洲周刊](http://www.yzzk.com), a weekly on politics, economics and culture.
2. [明報](http://www.mingpao.com/), founded by [Louis Cha Leung-yung](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E5%BA%B8), a renowned novel writer, and his co-founder in 1959.
3. [文匯報](http://www.wenweipo.com/), a left (pro-) newspaper. Founded in 1948.
4. [大公報](http://www.takungpao.com.hk/), another left newspaper. Founded in 1902.
5. [星島日報](http://www.singtao.com/), yet another left newspaper. Founded 1938.
6. [鳳凰網](http://www.ifeng.com), semi-official [CCTV](http://www.cntv.cn/index.shtml) like channel in Hong Kong.
7. [TVB無線新聞](http://news.tvb.com/), famous TV channel.
8. [壹週刊](http://hk.next.nextmedia.com/), a sibling of Taiwanese [蘋果日報](http://www.appledaily.com.tw), quite popular and entertaining.

### Taiwan

1. [中央社](http://www.cna.com.tw), a major news agency in Taiwan. Quite official. Founded in 1924.
2. [蘋果日報](http://www.appledaily.com.tw), a major daily. Good at entertaining people. I like its 3D video news.
3. [自由時報](http://www.libertytimes.com.tw/), as its name suggests, it's somewhat [Pan-Green](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%9B%E7%B6%A0). Founded in 1980.
4. [聯合報](http://udn.com/), a conservative major daily founded in 1951.
5. [中國時報](http://www.chinatimes.com/), a major daily. Founded in 1950.
6. [中央日報](http://www.cdnews.com.tw/), used to be official newspaper of the Kuomintang, founded in 1928.
7. [天下](http://www.cw.com.tw/), a financial-oriented magazine founded in 1981.
8. [商業周刊中文版](http://www.businessweekly.com.tw/), Taiwanese version of [Businessweek](http://www.businessweek.com/), with some local stories too.

Comment: That's the stuff. Excellent and extensive collection, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another source mentioning would be [The Marco Polo Project](http://marcopoloproject.org/online/). They have a lot of articles including translations (which you probably don't need). It still has 2 main advantages over other sources:

1. These articles are hand picked. So these are usually more interesting than the ones found on people.com.cn and the like.
2. They put their focus in selecting articles that are culturally valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in financial news, then:

1. [华尔街日报中文版 (Wall Street Journal)](http://cn.wsj.com/gb/)
2. [英国金融时报中文版 (Financial Times)](http://www.ftchinese.com/)

Comment: The articles in those sites read like an English original text translated to Chinese; I can tell from the grammatical style, which is sometimes awkward when rendered in Chinese. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Not so awkward, in my view, they're mixing together thanks to global trading, Chinese is flexible enough to absorb the essence and explore for new possibilities. 蓋臨川先生亦怪今之文體

Answer (score 0):

1) 慢速中文 
(Slowly Chinese)
http://www.slow-chinese.com/

2) 央视听新闻学汉语
 (Learn Chinese from listening news of CNTV) :
http://english.cntv.cn/program/learnchinese/specialchinese/

3) 网上孔子学院 (Confucius Institute online):
http://adult.chinese.cn/

4) 慢速中文 Podcast （对外汉语教学）:
Slowly Chinese Podcast (Teaching Chinese as a foreign language):
http://52podcast.com/slow-chinese.html

I recommend learning Chinese through listening first, then reading and speaking.

Comment: The links you gave seem to target Chinese learners, but OP's examples (NYT, Economist) are definitely for advanced English users. I think OP is trying to ask for Chinese news sources of an equivalent advanced level.

Comment: That is correct. I am more interested in advanced Chinese. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is: You'd better learn Pinyin at first for pronunciation. An advantage is that you can use Pinyin input method then. Then, you can read a <新华字典> Xinhua dictionary or some books to learn words. The most standard pronunciation is the hosts in CCTV speaks. So you can watch CCTV on web http://www.cntv.cn/.